# Why to use datatable when dataset is doing the same thing?

Tags: ado.net

My question is why do we use datatable when we have dataset which provides same functionality like datatable . Also its functionality is very vast(dataset). we can bind dataset to gridview than why to use datatable. Also we say that datatable,dataset,datareader represents an inmemory database so does it mean that that database tables store in our pc (physical disc) . What if we dont have sql server on our pc and using an application(web) that sends us tables(say 4)from physical storage database than in what format do the tables store.

Comment: If you only need one table - why use a `DataSet` which has all the overhead of supporting multiple tables and relationships between them? If you do need to keep multiple tables in memory - then use a `DataSet`.

Comment: to @marc_s: But if we have only one table in dataset that what to choose dataset or datatable.

Comment: If you only need **one table** - use a `DataTable` - no point and no benefit in using a `DataSet` for a single table !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataSet` does not provide same functionality as `DataTable`, `DataSet` is a collection of `DataTables`...

> The DataSet consists of a collection of DataTable objects that you can
>   relate to each other with DataRelation objects You can also enforce
>   data integrity in the DataSet by using the UniqueConstraint and
>   ForeignKeyConstraint objects. For further details about working with
>   DataSet objects, see DataSets, DataTables, and DataViews (ADO.NET).

As a result, there are times when it makes sense to use single, stand-alone `DataTable` but if you need to use related tables in order to enforce data integrity and have an in-memory [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) with foreign keys and/or unique constraints than you must use the `DataSet`.